# output from webcam and usb cam

Tags: ros, web, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using Electric on ubuntu 11.10. I have an integrated webcam and 2 usb cameras. When i launch stereo view i'm getting video from webcam and 1 usb cam. I need to stop video from webcam in order to set video from 2 usb cameras. How to do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31074/output-from-webcam-and-usb-cam/) by [nandhini](https://answers.ros.org/users/1736/nandhini/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-04-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken](https://answers.ros.org/users/13/ken/) on 2012-04-03**:
Which camera driver are you using?

**Comment by [nandhini](https://answers.ros.org/users/1736/nandhini/) on 2012-04-18**:
i'm using stereocamera-v4l2-ros-pkg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check the launch / config files. Your camera's are listed under /dev as video0, video1 and video2 probably. Change the config to video1 and video2.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2012-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1